# Jetty HttpClent error "java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException"

Tags: java, jetty, httpclient

I am currently working on a module in which I am using a Jetty HttpClient to send the data in JSON format to REST service running at server end.

**The use case in short:**

1. I have a CSV file with 10000 entries.
2. It is required to convert CSV entries into Java POJO object and then convert into JSON format.
3. Send the converted JSON format to REST web service running at server side.
4. It should also perform the authentication process while sending the data in JSON format to server using REST web service call.

**Problem:**
If I try to send all 10000 entries, along with authentication process I am getting below exception:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.getResult(FutureResponseListener.java:118)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.get(FutureResponseListener.java:101)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:653) 
>   Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException 
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:192)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:408)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.completeWrite(WriteFlusher.java:364)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint.onSelected(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:111)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.processKey(SelectorManager.java:636)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.select(SelectorManager.java:607)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.run(SelectorManager.java:545)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.NonBlockingThread.run(NonBlockingThread.java:52)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:170) 
>       ... 10 more

**Converting 10000 entries in batch**
If I convert all 10000 entries in batch (batch of for ex: 10). I am successfully able to send the data with same URL and authentication process.

The required code for reference is given below:

```
        String user = "myuser";
        String passwd = "mypassword";
        String relm = "Realm";

        String URL = "http://localhost:9123/path/to/rest/service/";

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.start();

        httpClient.setConnectTimeout(10000);

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String content = gson.toJson();

        AuthenticationStore authentication = httpClient.getAuthenticationStore();
        BasicAuthentication basicAuth = new BasicAuthentication(new URI(URL), relm, user, passwd);
        authentication.addAuthentication(basicAuth);

        StringContentProvider contentProvider = new StringContentProvider("application/json", content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        Request request = httpClient.newRequest(tURL);
        request.method(HttpMethod.POST);
        request.content(contentProvider);
        ContentResponse response = request.send();

        //ContentResponse response = httpClient.newRequest(URL).method(HttpMethod.POST).content(contentProvider).send();

        int status = response.getStatus();

        String reason = response.getReason();

        logger.info("REASON IS :: " + reason);
        logger.info("RESPONSE STATUS :: " + status);
```

Please help me resolving this issue.

Comment: What version of HttpClient?

Comment: Thanks Joakim for your response.  I am currently using jetty-all-9.2.10.v20150310 JAR file to use HttpClient.

Comment: I am having same issue with 9.2.22.v20170606